# Solutions of a non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on the following problem:
given the following differential equation
$$\ddot x(t)+\beta\sin(2\omega x(t))=0$$
and the initial conditions:
$$x(0)=x_0\space;\dot x(0)=x_1$$
is it possible to find a solution of this DE in a closed form? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the equaion by $x'$ and integrate once to obtain
$$
(x')^2-\frac{\beta}{\omega}\cos(2\,\omega\,x)=x_1^2-\frac{\beta}{\omega}\cos(2\,\omega\,x_0)=C.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{x'}{\sqrt{C+\dfrac{\beta}{\omega}\cos(2\,\omega\,x)}}=\pm1
$$
Mathematica gives an explicit expression for this integral in terms of elliptic functions.